# VMWare Player - Error converting to virtual machine

Tags: vmware-player

I'm trying to install the CS50 Appliance in VMWare Player, and it gives me an error saying 'Error converting to virtual machine - Unknown Error'. 
It advices me to contact VMWare technical support and provide the log file in 'users/AppData', but there is no folder called App Data. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

well the folder called AppData is located in your Username directory, it's there, just hidden (because normal users shouldn't mess with anything inside it). You either copy, edit and paste this in a file explorer Window:

C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\AppData\

Assuming you installed Windows in C, and running Window 7 up.

Where YourUserName is the name you initially gave your account.

**The other way you can do it** is: go to start > run > type in "%appdata%" (without quotes) and hit OK. This is a better one.

**[Here's is also a step-by-step tutorial on it doing it another way](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/cant-see-the-appdata-folder/)**

As for installing CS50, I've never done it before, but did you follow instructions [here](https://manual.cs50.net/appliance/19/player/)?

Also, this questions doesn't really belong in SO, you might want to try [Superuser](http://superuser.com) instead.

PS: Welcome to SO! :)